# Boot hangs on "Initialize hardware monitoring sensors"

Tags: lightdm, sensors, glib

My Ubuntu 19.04 installation does not boot up anymore.
It hangs on the message "Initialize hardware monitoring sensors":

[image]

I can log in however on terminal (eg TTY5)

Output of `journalctl`:

[image]

One red error reading:

"GLib: g_hash_table_foreach: assertion 'version == has_table -> version' failed"

How could I solve this?

FYI: I can start GUI on another TTY by using the command `sudo lightdm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get into the GUI again using this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then I selected `lightdm` as the default greeter and after reboot I was greeted with login screen again. I just notice some windows are different (eg logout) - this will probably be due to Ubuntu 19.04 using `gdm3` as default greeter but so far my laptop has been working fine.

Guess I'll just wait for the 19.10 upgrade after which `gdm3` will probably work again (this problem was introduced after installing updates anyway)